# Trying to reach rails app on shared server via subdomain, how?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to run a rails app (rails 4.0.0 and ruby 2.1.2p95) on a shared server. App is in "~/myapp" folder. I had to overcome some problems with runtime js. But managed to do that and was able to start the app, without any problems.

```
rails s -p 12001
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:12001
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2014-05-16 09:35:33] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-05-16 09:35:33] INFO  ruby 2.1.2 (2014-05-08) [x86_64-linux]
[2014-05-16 09:35:33] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=27965 port=12001
```

I am able to reach the app and see that it is actually working, if I add this in my ~/public_html/.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http://0.0.0.0:12001%{REQUEST_URI}" [P,QSA,L]
```

however this redirects my whole domain to the rails app. How could I do this for a subdomain? eg. mysubdomain.mydomain.com

thanks for any help :)